# Search with CakePHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, search

im new here and using CakePHP, I want make a searcher in my website but i have this error and warning:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: negocios [APP\View\Negocios\buscar.ctp, line 3]
>   Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Negocios\buscar.ctp, line 3]

This is my code from the controller:

```
<?php

class NegociosController extends AppController {

public $components = array('Paginator');
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

public function index(){
    $this->paginate = array('limit' => 1);
    $negocios = $this->paginate('Negocio');
    $this->set(compact('negocios'));
}


public function ver($id = null, $nombre){
    $this->Negocio->id = $id;
    $this->set('negocio', $this->Negocio->read());
}

public function buscar(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        $query = $this->data['Negocio']['buscador'];
        $this->set($query, $this->data['Negocio']['buscador']);
        $conditions = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'or' => array(
                    'Negocio.titulo LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.direccion LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.lugar LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.descripcion LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.direccion LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.email LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.web LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.facebook LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.twitter LIKE %$query%',
                    'Negocio.categoria LIKE %$query%'
                    )
                )
            );
        $this->set('negocios', $this->Negocio->find('all', $conditions));
    }
}

}

?>
```

My View:

```
<?php

foreach ($negocios as $key => $negocio) {
    echo $negocio['Negocio']['titulo'].'<br />';
    echo $negocio['Negocio']['descripcion'].'<br />';
    echo $negocio['Negocio']['categoria'].'<br />';

}

?>
```

@cornelb I have this:

```
<?php 

echo $this->Form->create(array('controller' => 'negocios', 'action' => 'buscar'));
echo $this->Form->input('buscador', array('placeholder' => 'Buscar negocios...', 'label' => false));
echo $this->Form->submit('search.png', array('type' => 'button', 'id' => 'buscar', 'div' => false));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

?>

and when im searching something i get this error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%$query%) OR (`Negocio`.`direccion` LIKE %$query%) OR (`Negocio`.`lugar` LIKE %$' at line 1

but if i use the "get" method i get nothing.

Comment: Your view code is messed up.

Comment: and... which view is that?

Comment: you are only sending $negocios to the view inside the " if(!empty($this->data)){" condition. You should send an empty one even if the user has not searched for anything. Does the search return anything?

Comment: @user221931 My view is obviously not finished, it was only to see if it worked and see the information displayed and i search something only can see this in my view "buscar.ctp" Notice (8): Undefined variable: negocios [APP\View\Negocios\buscar.ctp, line 3] Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Negocios\buscar.ctp, line 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would add the form to the view.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Negocio');
echo $this->Form->input('buscador');
echo $this->Form->submit('Search');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

And in the controller:

```
public function buscar(){
    $negocios = array();
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $query = $this->request->data['Negocio']['buscador'];
        $conditions = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'or' => array(
                    'Negocio.titulo LIKE' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.direccion LIKE' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.lugar LIKE' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.descripcion LIKE' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.direccion LIKE' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.email LIKE' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.web LIKE' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.facebook' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.twitter' => "%$query%",
                    'Negocio.categoria LIKE' => "%$query%",                    )
            )
        );
        $negocios = $this->Negocio->find('all', $conditions);
    }

    $this->set('negocios', $negocios);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have some problems can you check my post again i added information.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The syntax for %LIKE% was different (example: 'Negocio.titulo LIKE' => "%$query%"

Comment: thank you, problem solved :) , but i have another question, it is working now with post method but with get i get nothing in the search, why?

Comment: with get, the search  term will not be in $this->request->data. It should be in `$this->params` You can use `debug($this->params)` and see if that works

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help, and maybe im asking simple things but im new and im a little lost on some things.

Answer (score 1):

try this one .

```
'Negocio.titulo LIKE' => "%" . $query. "%",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Match Against Query also

```
$search = 'Search String';

$conditions = array( 
 "MATCH(Post.title) 
  AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" 
  );
 $matches = $this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

for Match Against you need to change table "Storage Engine" into "MYISAM" and also make fulltext index on fields.